# Mobile Friendly PayPal Buy Now Button

Tags: mobile, paypal, responsive-design

I've set up a Buy Now PayPal button on my site and everything works absolutely fine, including the PDT, etc.

However, on the mobile version of my site, the payment page is not at all mobile friendly. When the user clicks/taps "Buy Now", they are redirected to PayPal, but the screen that is displayed is not responsive.

I'm just using the standard code from the Buy Now button generated through PayPal. Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are some feature that is not supported on mobile checkout page.
If you use these the checkout page will still be a PC page.

Please refer to the page below:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/mobile-paypal-payments-standard/#usecases